# Why do my nested checkboxes only work once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adjusting an existing page where there are nested checkboxes, like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="categorycheckbox">Group 1</label>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label><input type="checkbox" class="productcheckbox">Item 1</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label><input type="checkbox" class="productcheckbox">Item 2</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="categorycheckbox">Group 2</label>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label><input type="checkbox" class="productcheckbox">Item 1</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label><input type="checkbox" class="productcheckbox">Item 2</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And so on. I'm using jQuery to give the users the ability to select/deselect all child inputboxes, like this:

```
var updateCheckedState = function () {
    var list = $(this).closest("li").find("ul");
    $(".productcheckbox", list).attr("checked", this.checked);
};

$(".categorycheckbox").change(updateCheckedState);
```

This works for checking once and unchecking once for each group. Then it stops working, and I don't understand why. I've created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AQ76y/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [prop instead of attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr).

```
$(".productcheckbox", list).prop("checked", this.checked);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfM2N/)

Because sometimes updating the attribute does not update the element property but using an prop and updating the property it is ensured that it will work across browsers.

*In earlier verisons of jquery attr used to do the work of prop, so it used to work then*